What is the advantage of the "Mechazilla arms" over fitting the Super Heavy booster with landing struts?
SpaceX lands the Falcon 9 booster stages on its built-in landing struts, this works well.
However, the plan to land the Super Heavy booster stage is to capture it in a set of mechanical arms dubbed "Mechazilla". This seems (to me) a more complicated procedure requiring more advanced hardware. The risk of extensive damage to ground-based structures in case of a failed landing also seems significantly higher.
So presumably there is a good reason why the Super Heavy booster would need to be captured upon landing rather than land on built-in struts. What is that reason?

Landing legs add mass. If the booster landed somewhere else, it would need to be transported to the tower for re-assembly, propellant re-load and launching; a non-trivial task. Overall, the tower grab is faster/better/cheaper/lighter.


This seems (to me) a more complicated procedure requiring more advanced hardware.

Not necessarily. Instead of thinking about "catching the booster with the arms", think about "the booster landing on the arms".
Imagine you take a Falcon 9 booster, but instead of putting the landing legs on the bottom, you put them on the top, and you dig a hole in the middle of the landing pad. That's kind of what we are talking about here.
The original idea was to land the booster directly back on the hold down clamps! Compared to that, the mechazilla catch sounds like a piece of cake.

The risk of extensive damage to ground-based structures in case of a failed landing also seems significantly higher.

Then don't fail the landing!
SpaceX has demonstrated more successful Falcon 9 landings in a row than most other launch systems even have total missions. We just had the 301st Falcon 9 landing, or the 318th, if you count Falcon Heavy center cores and side boosters, and the 244th consecutive successful landing (I lost count).
It will take a couple of tries, just like it did with Falcon 9, but practice makes perfect.

So presumably there is a good reason why the SuperHeavy booster would need to be captured upon landing rather than land on built-in struts. What is that reason?

Two reasons:

Mass savings: landing legs are heavy. The actuation mechanism is heavy.
Rapid turnaround: SpaceX wants the same booster to fly multiple times per hour. On Falcon 9, currently, it takes up to an hour to fold up the landing legs. In fact, on Falcon 9, the legs cannot fold up on their own, that can only be done externally. If you want to re-fly rapidly, the booster needs to be able to fold the legs up on its own – which again adds mass. And you pretty much have to land on or right next to the launch mount in order to enable such high cadence.

Remember:

Every kilogram of mass on the second stage costs one kilogram of payload.
Every kilogram of mass on the first stage costs roughly one quarter kilogram of payload.
Mass on the ground equipment (what SpaceX likes to call "Stage Zero") is free.

In fact, those numbers are for expendable vehicles. For reusable vehicles, the penalties are higher, because you not only have to lift the extra mass up, you also have to boost it back, and land it (and add the fuel for lifting it up, boosting it back, and landing it, and add the fuel for lifting the fuel, and add the fuel for that, and so on).

I hear what you say. Still... While every gram obviously counts, is the relative mass saving (struts vs. the entire booster assembly) really that significant? I understand that the booster has a dry weight well in excess of 160 tonnes. Also, flying the booster several times an hour may a stated goal, but between required checks, servicing, refueling and (last but not least) assembling the launch-ready stack of which the booster is part, folding the struts back up doesn't seem like it would slow down things all that much...

You kind of answered your own question, there.  The legs on the Falcon are huge and fairly heavy, and the SuperHeavy is an order of magnitude heavier. The landing legs needed to absorb that momentum would need to be absolutely massive, which is why it makes sense to offload that to a ground-based system. That limits superheavy to RTLS flight profiles (at least in the foreseeable future) but since they want to reuse it so rapidly, RTLS is going to be a requirement anyway.

It's not just the mass of the legs and shock absorbers (which would be considerable as described) It's also the mass of propellant required to accelerate the legs up to 5.5km/s and the mass of propellant required to boost the legs back to the landing site and land and the mass of propellant required to accelerate the return propellant up to 5.5km/s in the first place.

@Slarty: Good point! I completely overlooked that the 1:1, 4:1 number for payload penalty is for expendable rockets. For reusable ones, it would be even worse.

Adding to the rapid turnaround aspect, besides landing near the launchpad they would need to use a crane to lift the booster onto a transport stand and move it to the launch tower where it can be picked up by the arms, all of which takes time. The highest priority is for fast booster turnaround, it's not clear yet (possibly even to SpaceX) how fast ship turnaround will need to be. Ships and boosters don't need to remain paired up, prepared ships can be lined up for flight, a booster can land on the arms, be lowered onto the mount, get the next ship in line stacked on top, get refueled and go.

I suspect that if they did wind up having to go with landing legs (i.e. if catching just doesn't work out), they would probably not use a built-in retraction mechanism but would figure out a way to do that quickly using ground equipment. Similar to how they offloaded engine spin-up of the outer ring of Raptor engines to equipment on the orbital launch mount, saving weight on the booster.

OK - mass issues noted. :-) Has SpaceX said anything about what turnaround time they hope to achieve? Assuming there will be a market for launching the same booster multiple times per day or week, of course.

@FrankvanWensveen: Multiple launches per hour for the same booster, multiple launches per day for the same ship. So, booster turnaround < 30 minutes, ship turnaround < 12 hours. You need to launch "hundreds" of ships on each Mars transfer window, in order to get the rough estimate of 1 million tons of payload to Mars for an independent, self-sustaining civilization. You don't have to launch all of them at the same time, you can launch them one-by-one and have them all hang out in Earth orbit until the transfer arrives. Each of those will need 5–10 ships' worth of refilling.

So, with "hundreds" of ships every 26 months times 5–10 refilling ships for each of those, that's 500–1000 launches per year, roughly. And that's just for going to Mars, that does not include Starlink on Earth, a potential Moon base, or Starship point-to-point.

@JörgWMittag - it seems like turnaround times that short might not be necessary. Cape Canaveral even now could fairly easily support at least four Starship launch pads. 500 launches over a 30 day period on four pads is about four launches per day per pad, which would be a six-hour turnaround for each pad. Four boosters assigned to each pad would each fly once a day. Add a few offshore launch platforms and 1000 launches in 30 days is not far fetched. I'm starting to wonder if the spectacle of attempted booster catches might be short-lived and landing legs could eventually win out.

@StevePemberton That would require sustaining such a launch cadence over all of those 30 consecutive days, 24 hours a day. A few days of bad weather would be enough to derail the entire operation. To reliably pull it off within the constraints of the transfer window, you need to be able to launch at least tens of ships on a good day to compensate for all those bad days without launches.

@TooTea - that's true, and also launches that scrub for other reasons. The gas and go method being proposed will result in potentially more scrubs since there will be very little time for vehicle inspection prior to the next fueling/ignition attempt. Of course the goal is for this not to be the case, for it to be like refueling an airliner and only doing scheduled inspections after a certain number of launches. But that's an extreme goal, the reality may turn out to be finding a balance between recycling as quickly as possible and reducing the number of scrubs (and RUDs).
